# jupyter notebook dropdown menus not working

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

Recently the dropdown menus in jupyter / ipython notebook have stopped working. I'm loathe to do a full anaconda reinstall without first understanding what's going wrong.

Hopefully this gif is sufficiently self explanatory of the problem. There's no error messages appearing that I can see in terminal. The other buttons in the header still work.

[image]

Comment: A re there any error messages in the browser's Javascript console? Did you change anything recently, e.g. doing upgrades?

Comment: No consoles error message but that's a good point. It's possible this might coincide with an upgrade to my OS, I'll just reinstall Anaconda when I get the chance.

Comment: If you have another browser available, see if it works there.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just checked it there. It works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: I'd guess it's some kind of browser caching issue - if you hit Ctrl-F5 a few times in Chrome to force refresh, it will probably work.

Comment: I tried clearing the cache, cookies and app data on Chrome but it didn't seem to work. The issue has been a recurring one, not just with this notebook. Any notebook that's opened doesn't work.

Comment: I tried reinstalling Anaconda and the issue remains. I might log it as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running

```
conda update jupyter
```

seemed to the fix the problem somehow, even when reinstalling Anaconda did not.

Comment: I tried "conda update jupyter", but it didn't seem to help.  Jupyter Notebook does work fine in Firefox and Safari, though.  Only in Chrome have I encountered this problem.  (And only on the Mac, but I haven't tested on any other OS.)

Answer (score 1):

Updating jupyter did not work for me, however, disabling my pop-up blocker did the trick ('poper blocker' for Firefox in my case)

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, I could click on most of the menu items but just not the file menu. It wasn't an issue then one day it was. I deleted a chrome extension that I had: Kernel Hub, which I never used but was suppose to push kaggle updates to github, then I refreshed the page. I dunno if it was removing the extension up refreshing that fixed it but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a Chrome extension that caused the problem. I uninstalled it, reloaded the Jupyter Notebook page and the menus opened normally again.